# Still cant get icons on TabHost (HELP...)

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

The code below is from mainactivity but seem to have read every post on the net - but still cant find an example to help...

I want icons opposed to text on the tabhost

```
TabHost tabHost =(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
TabSpec tab1=tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
TabSpec tab2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
TabSpec tab3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Third Tab");

 tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Your Tab")
            .setIndicator("Login")
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));


 tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Your Tab")
            .setIndicator("Fare(s)")
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Tab2Activity.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));

 tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Your Tab")
            .setIndicator("Info")
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Tab3Activity.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
tabHost.getTabAt(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.icon4));
tabHost.getTabAt(1).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.icon3));
tabHost.getTabAt(2).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.icon2));
tabHost.getTabAt(3).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.icon1));
//Please note that R.mipmap.* stands for your icons storage location, it can be drawable or any other folder
```

Comment: The method getTabAt(int) is undefined for the type TabHost

Comment: why don't use instead `TabLayout` instead of `TabHost` I think tab icons were introduced with ``TabLayout` and are not compatible with `TabHost` if you want to switch I can help you with the code